# Converting C to Java - Pointer query

Tags: java, c, pointers

I'm converting a C prog that parses a text string and produces human readable o/p.

Got it nearly done, but having a problem understanding the difference in

```
*char_ptr++
```

and
`char_ptr--` in

```
 token[i++] = c = toupper(*char_ptr++);
 if (c == '\0')
   {
     char_ptr--;
     return( 0 );
   }
```

Am I correct in thinking that `*char_ptr++` will effectivley point to the next char in the 'string'?
If so, what does  `char_ptr--` do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Regard `*char_ptr++` as:

```
char tmp = *char_ptr;
char_ptr++;
c = toupper(tmp);
```

So it effectively fetches the current character, and advances the pointer by one. Because the `++` operator has a higher precedence than the unary `*`, such an expression is evaluated in the order `*(char_ptr++)`.

The incrementation is applied first, but since the postfix `++` operator returns the result prior to the manipulation, the `*` dereferencing operator is applied on the old address.

`char_ptr--` simply decreases the pointer by one.

Comment: Ah - so char_ptr-- is effectively *char_ptr--

Comment: No, the first means `n--`. The second means `arr[n--]`

Comment: Hmm - that's what confuses me :) Given a string, successive calls to *char_ptr++ will give the next character. I'd expect *char_ptr-- to give the previous. In which case, what does char_ptr-- do?

Comment: make a later call to *char_ptr return the previous.

Comment: Essentially `ptr++` or `ptr--` will change the value of `ptr[0]`.

Comment: Ah, got it. I think...  Cheers.

Comment: @Dave, no thats wrong :-/ `ptr++` and `ptr--` just increase or decrease an `int`. Exactly the same way as in Java. And you can not "call" `*char_ptr--`m as you say in your previous answer. @Blagovest Buyukliev, char_ptr is similar to an Iterator in Java. Imagine an iterator with 3 methods: advance, stepback, getValueAt. ++ advances, -- steps back, * is getValueAt(). Mixing * and ++ only means give me the value you have now and advance one stepp.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere. No. `ptr++` and `ptr--` change a `char *`. That is very different from an int.

Comment: Dave, please ... if you think so go back to school.

Comment: It's a number, but `sizeof(int)` may not equal `sizeof(char*)`. And I'd love to see a compiler let you dereference an `int`... Or are you just nitpicking my use of "call"? I know it's not a function, quit being pedantic.

Comment: @Dave Every old original K&R C compiler let you dereference an int. Being pedantic about "call" is important. This comment of you: "Essentially ptr++ or ptr-- will change the value of ptr[0]." is simply wrong. Place it in a file and compile it and see for your self in a debugger.

Comment: I should have said it "moves" ptr[0]. I never meant to imply that incrementing ptr increments ptr[0]; that'd be crazy. As for dereferencing an `int`; it's a blatant error on any C89 compiler. What type would the result even be?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as `++` increments the pointer and points to the next character, `--` decrements it, pointing to the previous character. In this case, it puts it back to the last real character from the terminating null.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're converting to java, you're going to have to remove the pointers, Java doesn't support them.

```
token[i++] = c = toupper(*char_ptr++);
if (c == '\0')
{
    char_ptr--;
    return( 0 );
}
```

Likely had some sort of declaration above it saying:

```
char* char_ptr = some_array;
```

Instead, that'll be

```
int pos = 0;
```

And the above code becomes:

```
token[i++] = c = toupper(some_array[pos++]);
if (c == '\0')
{
    pos--;
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? How is the program behaving?

Comment: Array out of bounds. I'll get there eventually!

Comment: Are Java strings null-terminated? Arrays in java have a `.length` field, so they might not be.

Comment: I've been initialisng the char[] with 0's and creating the strings in a loop. Fixed that prob now anyway. Evere onwards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.  It's a way of "peeking" ahead into the "string" and then returning to where you were if the string was at it's end.

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved by precedence rules. The expression

```
*char_ptr++
```

is resolved to

```
*(char_ptr++)
```

meaning "The character after the character that ptr is pointing to". So when c equals a '\0' (zero), the pointer gets decremented, so it points to the previous character. It practically decrements to the previous character whenever there's a 0 encountered, so that char_ptr points to whatever it pointed to during the last run of the block.